# How fix emacs error "old-style backquotes detected"

Tags: emacs, elisp

Any tips on fixing the emacs error "old-style backquotes detected"?

I'm sure the error is coming from some ancient lisp code I wrote.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting a similar error. How do you find the lines that have the error ?  Do I need to look for every use of a ` and fix it ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Are you using the old code with an old or a recent Emacs version (or both)? If you do not need the old backquotes-style code then just replace it with the current style. The Elisp manual tells you how to use backquote.

In general, in the old style:

- You needed an extra pair of parens surrounding the whole sexp.
- Each construct, such as `,...` and `,@...` was handled like a function: `(,...)` and `(,@...)`.

Example with new syntax:

```
`(foo ,bar ,@toto)
```

Example with old syntax:

```
(` (foo (, bar) (,@ toto)))
```

Comment: @Doorknob: (1) Why ask that in the context of this unrelated answer? (2) What is wrong with the question you refer to? Please be specific, preferably pointing to relevant guidelines. I don't see that asking for suggestions about an intro Java book violates this, for example: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." If such spam results for this question, then I will vote to close it. Otherwise, such a programming-related question can help. What am I missing?

Comment: (1) Because I had nowhere else to ask it. (2) That exact reason. It doesn't matter when it starts attracting spam. For example, if you saw a tiger staring at you, would you ignore it until it bit you? Also, it's clearly not even a question; just "please give me links."

Comment: @Doorknob: I don't feel strongly about it - it's OK with me to close it. Is there a way to change my vote now? I haven't found one. IMHO, however, a newbie question for technical book suggestions to learn a programming topic should not be discouraged offhandedly. Others can learn from reading the comments and answers to this question. And there was no abuse (opinionated answers or spam) in this case. I don't see a tiger here, not yet anyway. YMMV.